# How to reference an overridden server control on a page in a Web Application

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to create an override of the ASP.Net Menu control so that I can replace the onhover behavior with onclick behavior to make it more friendly for mobile browsers that don't fire an onhover event when an item is clicked.

So far I have created the following class in the App_Code folder (I have also tried creating it outside the App_Code folder with the same result):

```
Imports System.IO

Namespace vscm
    Public Class SNAPMenu
        Inherits System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu
        Protected Overrides Sub Render(writer As HtmlTextWriter)
            Dim sb As New StringBuilder
            Dim sw As New StringWriter(sb)

            Dim hw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
            MyBase.Render(hw)

            Dim html As String = sb.ToString
            html = html.Replace("onmouseover=""Menu_HoverStatic(this)""", "onclick=""Menu_HoverStatic(this)""")

            writer.Write(html)
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

I have added the following line to my aspx file that is intended to host the custom menu:

```
<%@ Register Namespace="vscm" TagPrefix="vscm" %>
```

However, when I try to add the custom menu to the page using

```
<vscm:SNAPMenu runat="server" id="MainMenu"></vscm:SNAPMenu>
```

I receive the error: Type 'Global.vscm.SNAPMenu' is not defined.
Mousing over the "

ASP.NET runtime error: The base class includes the field 'MainMenu', but its type (VSC_40.VSC_40.vscm.SNAPMenu) is not compatible with the type of control (vscm.SNAPMenu).

I've done a lot of Googling, but so far haven't been able to figure this out. I'm assuming I'm just referencing things incorrectly but am at a loss. Anyone out there that can point me in the right direction to include this overridden control on a page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your web application is called "vscm" you can remove the namespace from your overridden control and place it at the base of your project.  When you register it on your aspx page you'll need to include both the `Assembly` and `Namespace` attributes.

### Add Your Class to the Project Root

[image]

### Remove the Namespace in the Class Definition

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class SNAPMenu
Inherits System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu

    Protected Overrides Sub Render(writer As HtmlTextWriter)
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder
        Dim sw As New StringWriter(sb)

        Dim hw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
        MyBase.Render(hw)

        Dim html As String = sb.ToString
        html = html.Replace("onmouseover=""Menu_HoverStatic(this)""", "onclick=""Menu_HoverStatic(this)""")

        writer.Write(html)
    End Sub

End Class
```

### Register Your Custom Control on the Page

```
<%@ Register Assembly="vscm" Namespace="vscm" TagPrefix="vscm" %>
```

### Finally, Use your Custom Menu

```
<vscm:SNAPMenu runat="server" id="ManuMenu"></vscm:SNAPMenu>
```

I made a few assumptions about the nature of your project so your mileage may vary.

Comment: Awesome, that did the trick. Didn't realize I had to reference the assembly even though I was in the same assembly. Now all I have to do is get the actual override doing what I need it to do, but that is outside the scope of this question.